# C++ - need suggestion on 2-d Data structure - size of 1-D is not fixed

Tags: data-structures

I wish to have a 2-D data structure to store SAT formulas. What I want is similar to 2-D arrays. But I wish to do dynamic memory allocation.

I was thinking in terms of array of vectors of the following form :-

```
typedef vector<int> intVector;
intVector *clause;
clause = new intVector [numClause + 1] ;
```

Thus `clause[0]` will be one vector, `clause[1]` will be another and so on. And each vector may have a different size. But I am unsure if this is the right thing to do in terms of memory allocation.

Can an array of vectors be made, so that the vectors have different sizes ? How bad is it on memory management ?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by SAT formulas, but there are various ways to do 2d arrays with varying "row size", and yours is as good as others

Comment: A SAT formula is a "Boolean Satisfiabiliy Formula" - basically, it's a boolean logical expression which is "satisfiable" if there's at least one way to assign variables such that the expression is true. To the asker, vectors use dynamic memory allocation internally (that's why you're able to resize them and such); typically, you wouldn't mix manual dynamic allocation and vectors. Instead, use a vector of vectors or dynamically allocate two levels deep.

Comment: @IanPudney , so you are suggesting that instead of intVector *clause, I use a vector of vectors ? . Thing is the number of Rows is pretty much fixed in my case. Hence i was thinking on the lines of array of vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To memory management will be fine using STL (dynamic memory alloc), performance will go down because is dynamic and doesn't do direct access.

If you're in complete dispair you may use a vector of pairs, with the first as an static array and the second, the count of used elements.  If some array grows bigger, you may reallocate with more memory and increase the count.  This will be a big mess, but may work.  You'll lose less memory and make direct acess to the second level of arrays, but is ugly and dirt.

Comment: Most of the time the rowsize would equal 3. But in some cases it may grow larger. So I was thinking in terms of array of vectors . There won't be direct access but 80-90% of the time the row size would be less than 5, so it would be O(1) access time most of the time .

Comment: Well.  In this case the direct acess won't be a great deal.  Using an vector of vectors shall work fine, you won't get memory problems and performing smoothly.  STL is gold.